# Using atan2 with offset circle

Tags: javascript, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the Arc Length, so that I can color my circle border given the Arc Length.

Users can click on the circle edge and the code should automatically calculate the Arc Length from position `y=radius` `x=cx`. Given the function `atan2()`, I cannot achieve this successfully, because if I understand correctly, `atan2` return the angle between positive X-axis and the ray from my center of circle towards the point clicked. But I need the angle between the point clicked and the y-axis.

I am attaching the picture, in case it will make more sense:
[image]

What I have currently is:

```
// Calcualte the deltas for point X and Y which are required for atan2 function
let deltaX = event.pageX - this.centerX
let deltaY = event.pageY - this.centerY

// The Math.atan2() function returns the angle in the plane (in radians) between the positive x-axis and the ray from (0,0) to the point (x,y), for Math.atan2(y,x)
let angleRadian = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX)
// Apply formula to calculate Arc length
let arcLength = radius * angleRadian
```

I am aware that atan2 calculates the angle as I described above, but I do not know how to modify my code to achieve what I need it to do - that is, get the angle between the Point Clicked and the y-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap `atan2` arguments to get angle from OY axis.
For counterclockwise (CCW) system:

```
let angleRadian = Math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY)
```

(based on formulas `cos(a)=sin(Pi/2-a), sin(a)=cos(Pi/2-a)`)

For clockwise (CW) system, where OY axis direction is down:

```
let angleRadian = Math.atan2(deltaX, -deltaY)
```

Comment: I tried that already, but it does not work. I believe I should also handle some cases where `deltaY` and `deltaX` are negative values, but I am not sure how.

Comment: It definitely works. But what is your OY axis direction - up or down? Perhaps you are tangled with coordinate system. In clockwise system you have to change also sign of one argument. Handling negative offsets depends on your purposes - perhaps you can use absolute value of result

Comment: If you look at my picture in my question, the direction is clockwise. So when user clicks on the circle, the arc should be calculated from the y = radius  and the point where the user clicked in clockwise direction.

Comment: I see cx=200, cy=200 for small circle, so decided you mean CCW system.  Use `atan2(deltaX, -deltaY)` for CW system

Comment: Oh sorry, I just used the 'naming' that I saw on web for such equations. With cx and cy I meant as 'center' of my circle, which is not necessarily in the 0,0 point.

Comment: That one works! Could you please kindly also update the answer with your explanation about CCW vs CW. I would really like to understand this difference more and why does simple 'inversoin' (-) makes it work.

Comment: Added both cases